# Save Datagrid data to SQL Server database in VB.Net

Tags: sql-server, database, vb.net, datagridview

I have a datagrid with data. Column one is a combobox with importers whereas column two is the quantity imported. I want to be able to save this data to the DB irrespective of the user's selection.

Please see my code show below. Can someone help me out?

```
Dim intReturnValue As Integer = 0

Dim SqlCmd As String = "Update Importer_Balance SET Quantity = Quantity + @Quantity WHERE Importer=@Importer and Product=@product" 

Dim ConnObj As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(clsGlobals.ConnString)
Dim CmdObj As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(SqlCmd, ConnObj)

For i = 0 To Me.dgvImporter.RowCount - 1
        CmdObj.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Importer", Me.dgvImporter.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value)
        CmdObj.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", Me.dgvImporter.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value)
        CmdObj.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Product", cboProductName.SelectedValue)
Next

ConnObj.Open()

intReturnValue = CInt(CmdObj.ExecuteNonQuery())

ConnObj.Close()

If intReturnValue > 0 Then
        MsgBox("You have successfully updated the product table product.", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "")
        ClearForm()
Else
        MsgBox("No Record were inserted", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "")
End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the loop you add the parameters but don't execute the command, this will work only if you have just one row and results in an error if you have to update more than one row.
You continue to readd the same parameters at each loop to the same command.

Instead move the declaration of the parameters before the loop and inside the loop just set their values and then execute the command.

```
Dim intReturnValue As Integer = 0
Dim SqlCmd As String = "Update Importer_Balance SET Quantity = Quantity + @Quantity WHERE Importer=@Importer and Product=@product" 

Dim ConnObj As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(clsGlobals.ConnString)
Dim CmdObj As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(SqlCmd, ConnObj)
CmdObj.Parameters.Add("@Importer", SqlDbType.Int)
CmdObj.Parameters.Add("@Quantity", SqlDbType.Int)
CmdObj.Parameters.Add("@Product", SqlDbType.Int)
ConnObj.Open()

For i = 0 To Me.dgvImporter.RowCount - 1
    CmdObj.Parameters("@Importer").Value = Convert.ToInt32(Me.dgvImporter.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value)
    CmdObj.Parameters("@Quantity").Value = Convert.ToInt32(Me.dgvImporter.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value)
    CmdObj.Parameters("@Product").Value = Convert.ToInt32(cboProductName.SelectedValue)
    intReturnValue = CInt(CmdObj.ExecuteNonQuery())

Next
```

**Important note.** `AddWithValue` discovers the datatype of the parameter looking at the value passed. This assumption is dangerous and could lead to errors. It is better to use the specialized constructor where you can define the type and the size of the parameter

Comment: Steve. Thanks for the response. After reviewing my code and following your suggestions, I am getting this error: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter'.

Comment: My bad, missing Value in the last parameter

Comment: Prior to your response, I enclosed the entire code into the loop. The error I got is similar to the one I am receiving after following the instruction. The error is: The parameterized query '(@Importer nvarchar(4000),@Quantity nvarchar(4000),@Product int)' expects the parameter '@Importer', which was not supplied.

Comment: But this seems not logical. Quantity field should not be a string. What datatype are these fields on the database?

Comment: All fields are integer. Importer and Product are foreign keys in the database.

Comment: Then we need to pass INTEGERS not strings. I will update the answer

Comment: Ok Thanks for the time. This is what I want to achieve. I have a datagrid with three columns. The first column has a combobox with a list of importers. The second is a textbox where user will enter the quantity supplied. The third is the unit (Metric Tons or gallons). After an importer is selected, the valuemember and not the displaymember is what I need to complete the query.

Comment: Sorry but can't debug the program from here. Try to use the debugger, put a breakpoint on the line that extracts the values and pass them to your parameters. Look what values are passed to the parameters. Something should be different from what you expect to be.

Comment: Thanks Sir. It is working perfectly now. I highly appreciate your effort.

Comment: Ok thanks. I shall make the forum a place for all my queries.