# How to add multiple records in SQL Server using DataGridView

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I'm using VB.Net with SQL Server and I'm trying to integrate values modified in a `DataGridView` into a SQL Server database. Some guidance on how to go about this would be appreciated.

Comment: Please add the code that you have written so far.

Comment: I just want to know the method that achieves this treatment

Comment: Take a look at this question: [Save Datagrid data to SQL Server database in VB.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26192477/save-datagrid-data-to-sql-server-database-in-vb-net). You may find it a helpful guide.

Comment: Private Sub DataGridView1_CellValueChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellValueChanged
        If sql.connect = True Then
            Dim i As New Integer

            While (i < DataGridView1.RowCount)


                sql.exereq("update avance set montant='" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value & "' where  IdFuncionario='" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value & "'")
                i += 1
            End While
        End If
    End Sub

Answer (score 0):

There is the code

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellValueChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellValueChanged
        If sql.connect = True Then
            Dim i As New Integer

            While (i < DataGridView1.RowCount)


                sql.exereq("update avance set montant='" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value & "' where  IdFuncionario='" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value & "'")
                i += 1
            End While
        End If
    End Sub
```